# Avalonia - How to place the Tab control's tabs vertically like the OneNote Desktop UI

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I am new to Avalonia. In WPF, you can easily place the tab control's tabs vertically, demonstrated in below article 
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/tabcontrol/tab-positions/

How could I achieve similar things in Avalonia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found out, identical to WPF, set the attribute `TabStripPlacement` to `Left` will do the trick, like below

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
```